# Access s3 bucket from other region using java aws-java-sdk

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

I have s3 bucket from ap-south-1 which I have accessing using aws java sdk
 `AmazonS3 amazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard(). withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1).defaultClient();`

`awazonS3.putObject(putObjectRequest);`

It was working fine when my service is running in "ap-south-1". Now, when I move the service moved to "ap-south-2" reason same code is giving error.

```
The ap-south-1 location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: IllegalLocationConstraintException; Request ID: TTTTDW5T2GF0J28S8; S3 Extended Request ID: l3djAuSl5RXWgSLn12gTnyXyF1P7Q60OAMxTNhyrnmIJxIZ2MjRRzmOMT1hsEW6+KjqA=; Proxy: null)
```

currently i m using

```
    `<dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.145</version>
    </dependency>`
```

I want to access same bucket of **ap-south-1** in **ap-south-2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are using `.defaultClient()` which I think ignores the Region you set

Try using `.build()` instead which [Builds a client with the configure properties](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/client/builder/AwsSyncClientBuilder.html#build--).

so

```
AmazonS3 amazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                    .standard()
                    .withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1)
                    .build();
```

Note, you can also specify the S3 endpoint explicitly, as follows (but the above code is simpler):

```
AmazonS3 amazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                    .standard()
                    .withEndpointConfiguration(
                       new EndpointConfiguration("https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com", "ap-south-1"))
                    .build();
```